# My haml view is unable to find the css file in my public/css folder when deployed, but manages to find it on localhost

Tags: css, ruby, sinatra, haml, passenger

My application is running on Sinatra and deployed on my Apache web server using Passenger. My directory structure is as follows:

```
approot
` public
  ` css
    - bootstrap.css
  ` uploads
    - empty.txt
` tmp
  - restart.txt
` views
  - success.haml
  - upload.haml
- config.ru
- myapp.rb
```

**Inside upload.haml**

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css")
```

When I run this application on localhost:4567, the CSS loads just fine. However, when I deploy it on my web server, the CSS doesn't load.

On my web server, the application is accessed using: `rubyapps.mydomain.com/appname`

And if I type: `rubyapps.mydomain.com/appname/css/bootstrap.css`, I am able to see the contents of my CSS file just fine.

Totally confused, and not getting how Sinatra handles this situation, looking for a little help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be running into the need to use Sinatra's [URL helper](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro#Generating%20URLs).

```
For generating URLs you should use the url helper method, for instance, in Haml:

%a{:href => url('/foo')} foo

It takes reverse proxies and Rack routers into account, if present.

This method is also aliased to to (see below for an example).
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="../public/css/bootstrap.css")
```

Or...

```
%link(rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.css")
```

Comment: No unfortunately not. I tried these first thing. The thing is, when I do "View Source" I can see that my HTML file that is being generated is linking to "css/bootstrap.css" and my URL at that point is http://rubyapps.mydomain.com/appname/ -- And if I manually type http://rubyapps.mydomain.com/appname/css/bootstrap.css it actually displays the file.

Comment: Okay so what I did was, added the appname to the stylesheet, link, i.e. %link(rel="stylesheet" href="appname/css/bootstrap.css") and it worked. However, now this means that on my localhost, it will be broken :/